# character keeps shaking while in topdown shooter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, top-down

ok well i am working on a top down shooter i have made my character look at the mouse using screentoworld view and i made my camera follow my players x, and z axis but anytime my character moves parallel from the mouse it starts shaking  I think its because it looks at the mouse an the mouse real world position is dependent on the cameras position  which is, but i am not sure.

here is the playerscript  the many backslashes showed other things I've tried

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")*movementspeed,0,Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")*movementspeed);  
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.x != 0 && gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.z != 0) {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")*movementspeeddiag ,0,Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")*movementspeeddiag); 
        }

    // makes vector 3 type target equall to mouse position on pixial cordinates converted in to real world coordniates
        target = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,camera.transform.position.y - transform.position.y)); 

        //Vector3 newtarget = target - transform.position;

        //lerptarget = Vector3.Lerp (transform.eulerAngles,newtarget, 100);
        // states the vector 3 values of target 

        // makes object local z face target and iniziates up axis 

        //Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (newtarget, Vector3.up); 

        //transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle (transform.eulerAngles.y, rotation.eulerAngles.y, rotatespeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.LookAt (target,Vector3.up);
```

and camera script

```
    void LateUpdate(){
        position = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x, 10, player.transform.position.z); 
        transform.position = position;
        //transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, position, speed *Time.deltaTime); 

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (90,0,0); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the problem is that you change the velocity of rigidbody. Becouse velocity changes applied each fixed update time interval, it doesnt match with frame updating time, and may lead to shaking. According to unity docs you should try to avoid directly changes of velocity. (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

I'd suggest you to you use MovePosition alongside with Lerp function to implement player movement. 
See this:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: OK i tried rigidbody.moveposition and I'm sorry to say but its really horrible i didn't add the lerp functionality yet but it already seems buggy it stops the player randomly at different spots while walking and it still shakes.

Comment: Ok i fixed the problem with the problem with the player stopping randomly, but it still keeps shaking, and i don't know why i really don't want to us lerp because i want my character to ave that old school snappy control feel. please help thank you this does not seem to be a problem for no one else just me I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you sir for all your help turns out it wasn't the velocity at all it was the frame rates. I was rotating the player in the Update() while moving him in the Fixedupdate() while moving the camera in the LateUpdate() I ended up putting all of hem in the FixedUpdate, and now it works good thank you again.